# Using regEx to download the entire directory using wget

Tags: regex, shell, cygwin, wget, http-status-code-403

I want to download multiple pdfs from urls such as this - `https://dummy.site.com/aabbcc/xyz/2017/09/15/2194812/O7ca217a71ac444eda516d8f78c29091a.pdf`

If I do wget on complete URL then it downloads the file `wget https://dummy.site.com/aabbcc/xyz/2017/09/15/2194812/O7ca217a71ac444eda516d8f78c29091a.pdf`

But if I try to recursively download the entire folder then it returns 403(forbidden access)

```
wget -r https://dummy.site.com/aabbcc/xyz/
```

I have tried by setting user agent, rejecting robots.txt and bunch of other solutions from the internet, but I'm coming back to same point.

So I want to form the list of all possible URLs considering the given URL as common pattern, and have no idea how to do that.

I just know that I can pass that file as input to wget which will download the files recursively. So seeking the help for forming the URL list using regEx here.
Thank You!

Comment: Regex does not _generate_ possible matches. It matches _existing_ ones.

Comment: Yes, sorry for causing the confusion. What I want is a script which will loop over the common pattern(which I assumed can be done using Regex) and generate all the combinations of URLs, which can be passed on to wget, it will download from the URLs that actually exist, or move on.

Comment: wget just follows links--if you just point it to some URL it can't magically find any valid sub-URLs it might be able to download if there's no directory listing (which on most modern websites there won't be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't download using wildcard the files you can't see. If the host do not support directory listing you have no idea what the filenames/paths are. Also as you do not know the algorithm to generate filenames you can't generate and get them.